# Magento 1.9.1 - How to save estimated delivery date

Tags: magento

I am trying to find how to save estimated delivery date, so that it gets displayed in order page.

In short, i have the estimated delivery date  (internal calculation) but don't know how and where to save it.

Comment: You should be able to do [something like this](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/3810/20131), but instead save your calculated date to the quote/order.

Comment: Thanks. How do i add the calculated date to the quote/order ? Could you please point me to a sample code?

Comment: What have you tried so far? The answer I linked to contained an example to do almost exactly what you need, so adapt should be able to adapt it to your value instead.